# Google sheets published csv sometimes yields html instead of csv

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

The following code

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQDGHMz-ynciGYoHe7Nma6r99qHkscebte8I9COd6dmGZ4jWZtA4_q7U3NT9cPut3v6pmZY5errsS0R/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'

import requests, io
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.content

import pandas as pd
print(data)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), encoding='utf8', sep=",")
```

has output

```
b'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n  <head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8">[...];\n  </script>\n  </body>\n</html>\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), encoding='utf8', sep=",")
  File "C:\Users\dleve\anaconda3\envs\aaroneller\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\dleve\anaconda3\envs\aaroneller\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 458, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\dleve\anaconda3\envs\aaroneller\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1196, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\dleve\anaconda3\envs\aaroneller\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2155, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 918, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 905, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2042, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

with much longer output for the data.

pd.read_csv(url) shows the same error, so I believe that data is an accurate display of what pd.read_csv is receiving. Why is it an html instead of a csv?

Note that the following, link obtained precisely the same way (publish to csv), produces a csv output.

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQG30aRS6AcBtWEzeDQtJJXxwwrDHCg0fqKo3v4GgO5ijbWks__htH0gIQqgb6sQDK4Q87aFttaAijf/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'

import requests, io
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.content

import pandas as pd
print(data)
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), encoding='utf8', sep=",")
```

produces

```
b'A,B,C\r\n1,2,3\r\n4,5,6'
```

and pd.read_csv(url) in this case works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first url links to a Google Sheets document that does not allow access from all users, so it produces an HTML response telling the user to ask for authorization from the sheet owner. The second url links to a Google Sheets document that lets anyone access it using the link, so it generates CSV as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the response to the url which is a Google Sheet csv download link, not the csv itself. Content will be html.

Comment: It's really not that simple though; a nearly identical example url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQG30aRS6AcBtWEzeDQtJJXxwwrDHCg0fqKo3v4GgO5ijbWks__htH0gIQqgb6sQDK4Q87aFttaAijf/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'
provides a csv output.